# preg_match for every enclosed text that exists, repeat a function

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In a string I have somthing like this:

```
[select|blog]
    Some text some text some text
[/select]

more text more text more text

[select|information]
    Some text some text some text
[/select]
```

Now using preg_match I would like the function to:

- get the text between the [select] tags
- change it
- insert it back into the string
- remove the select tags

So in the end it will become something like this:

```
Changed text1 Changed text1 Changed text1

more text more text more text

Changed text2 Changed text2 Changed text2
```

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks! :)

Comment: You will find your get a better quality of answer and that people are more willing to help you if you are able to demonstrate that you have [tried something for yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) would probably be the place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will get you started

```
\[.*?](.*?)\[.*?]
```

Put the option on that allows the dot . to match new line

The text inside the brackets is in group 1

I'm coming from the .NET world so I would tackle this with a function that I can let get executed after each match.
The input of this function is the match. Here you can get to group 1 if you need to access to it and rewrite or put your new content.

I just read in the comments that the equivalent in php is `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: +1, and additional hint: the `/s` PCRE modifier will help here

Comment: buckley, why do i get this error when i start out with your regex: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in...

Comment: Figured out that brackets had to go around the whole pattern also: 
(\{select\|(.*?)}(.*?)\{/select.*?})

Thanks ;)